# gcloud ML engine - Keras not running on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning

I'm new with Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine, 
I'm trying to train a DL algorithm for image classification based on Keras in gcloud. 
In order to configure the GPU on gcloud I have included `'tensorflow-gpu'` in the `setup.py install_requires`. 
My `cloud-gpu.yaml` is the following

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: BASIC_GPU
  runtimeVersion: "1.0"
```

In the code I've added:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

at the beginning and

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
```

before any Keras code.

The result is that gcloud is recognising the gpu but not using it, as you can see from

Screenshot of actual cloud training:

```
INFO    2018-11-18 12:19:59 -0600   master-replica-0        Epoch 1/20
INFO    2018-11-18 12:20:56 -0600   master-replica-0          1/219 [..............................] - ETA: 4:17:12 - loss: 0.8846 - acc: 0.5053 - f1_measure: 0.1043
INFO    2018-11-18 12:21:57 -0600   master-replica-0          2/219 [..............................] - ETA: 3:51:32 - loss: 0.8767 - acc: 0.5018 - f1_measure: 0.1013
INFO    2018-11-18 12:22:59 -0600   master-replica-0          3/219 [..............................] - ETA: 3:46:49 - loss: 0.8634 - acc: 0.5039 - f1_measure: 0.1010
INFO    2018-11-18 12:23:58 -0600   master-replica-0          4/219 [..............................] - ETA: 3:44:59 - loss: 0.8525 - acc: 0.5045 - f1_measure: 0.0991
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0          5/219 [..............................] - ETA: 3:41:17 - loss: 0.8434 - acc: 0.5031 - f1_measure: 0.0992Sun Nov 18 18:24:48 2018       
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        | NVIDIA-SMI 396.26                 Driver Version: 396.26                    |
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        |===============================+======================+======================|
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        |   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        | N/A   32C    P0    56W / 149W |  10955MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0                                                                                       
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        | Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        |  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        |=============================================================================|
INFO    2018-11-18 12:24:48 -0600   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Basically the GPU usage stays at 0% during the training, how can this be possible?

Comment: Pleas provide actual code / text instead of screenshots, since your image could disappear from hosting service.

Comment: Thank You, I've added the actual terminal code

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the [`standard_gpu`](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/machine-types#machine_type_table) which has the same n1-standard-8 with one k80 GPU in the `cloud-gpu.yaml`:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  # standard_gpu provides 1 GPU. Change to complex_model_m_gpu for 4 GPUs
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "1.5"
```

this:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
```

[should be](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#supported_devices):

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
```

I recommend to review this [cnn_with_keras.py](https://github.com/Neeraj-Natu/keras-cloud-test/blob/master/trainer/cnn_with_keras.py) to have a better example.